# When importing data to the graph database Galaxybase using the import tool galaxybase-load, how should the value of the alias field be configured?

Tags: graph-databases

When using the import tool galaxybase-load to import data into the graph database Galaxybase, a mapping.json file is needed. If the value of the "hasHeader" field in the mapping.json file is "false", how should the "alias" field be configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "alias" field needs to be filled with the property names of vertex and edge types in the graph model. The "alias" field is not related to the "hasHeader" field, as they have different meanings and refer to different objects.

The "alias" field is related to the "columnName" and "columnIndex" fields, which specify which columns from the data source will be imported into the property specified by "alias".

The "hasHeader" field indicates whether the data source has a header row. If this field is set to "true", the first row will be treated as the header and not imported. The "hasHeader" field is only supported for CSV, socket, and HDFS CSV data sources, which use the "columnIndex" field to specify columns.

For data sources such as JDBC and HDFS Parquet, which use the "columnName" to specify columns, the "hasHeader" field does not need to be filled. Therefore, there is no data source that requires both "hasHeader" and "columnName" to be set at the same time.